# Multiplying a number with percentage to get a determined sum

Tags: percentages

What percentage do we have to multiply with 125 dollars to get 355 dollars?

125(100/x) = 355

12500/x= 355

12500 = 355*x

x = 12500/355 = 35,211…

125 dollars * 1,35 = 168.75 dollars (wrong)

125 dollars * 3,5 = 437.5 dollars (also wrong)

Comment: Try using $\frac{x}{100}$ instead of $\frac{100}{x}$ in your equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$125\cdot\frac{x}{100}=355$$
$$x=\frac{355\cdot100}{125}=284$$
$$125\cdot2.84=355$$